# arraylist - not getting expected data

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to fetch some data from database and trying to display the same using simple array list concept. But i am not getting expected data. Please help me on where i did mistake or missed any.

```js
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.List;

public class testing {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Elements> itemList = new ArrayList<Elements>();
  try
      {      
    System.out.println("I am in");  
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("db connection");
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       System.out.println("Connection estabilished"+con);
       
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select itemname, itemcode,supplier,totalqty from table where condition");
       
       while(rs.next()) { 
                 Elements item=new Elements();
                 item.setItemname(rs.getString("Itemname"));
                 item.setItemcode(rs.getString("Itemcode"));
                    item.setSupplier(rs.getString("Supplier"));
                    item.setTotalqty(rs.getString("Totalqty"));
                 itemList.add(item);
                  System.out.println(itemList.size());
                     System.out.println(itemList.get(1).getItemname());

                }
       con.close(); 
       out.println("DB Connection closed successfully");   
       
      }catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("Connection error: "+e);
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: by mistake that happened

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Also, I noticed that System.out.println(itemList.get(1).getItemname()); is inside the while loop, which should cause first iteration to throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Yes! thats the mistake. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)